# Retrieve amount of time in days a field remains in a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and have a table that audit all changes made to another table, and have this for example:

```
Old Value    New Value    Time
Not Found    Open         2014-02-10 14:11:09.000
Open         Fixed        2014-03-06 05:35:04.000
Fixed        Open         2014-03-27 11:44:40.000
Open         Fixed        2014-04-10 10:00:54.000
```

I want to calculate the amount of time it was in "Open", note that this is just an example and the real table will have rows in between those presented.

For instance I want to get something like this:

```
Record Id    Time Open (days)         
1            2        
2            7        
3            5 
...          ...
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide desired results in the question.

Comment: How about some table definition and sample data that actually match each other? There is no "Record Id" in your "table". Create a sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) with your table and sample data. Then explain what you expect for output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a key for each Open Item, it takes a little manipulation of times to get what you are asking for.

Try this, it will provide the number of days between the "Open" insert and the first "Fixed" insert following the Open item.

```
Select RecordId,DateDiff(Day,StartTime,EndTime) as TimeOpen
From
(
    Select Rank() OVER (ORDER BY UpdateTime) RecordId,
        UpdateTime as StartTime, 
        (Select MIN(T2.UpdateTime) from MyTable T2 where T2.UpdateTime > T1.UpdateTime and T2.New_Value = 'Fixed') EndTime 
    from MyTable T1
    where New_Value = 'Open'
) A
```